# how to make whitespace into consideration in C when dealing with command line args

Tags: c

I am trying to deal with the command line arguments but the command line args include whitespaces which I need to make into consideration.

Here is my code and I am trying to deal with the following command line args:

- if I type in "-upper" as the command args then it changes the text to upper cases/
- if I type in "-lower" then it changes the text to lower cases/
- if I type in "-upper -lower" then it only changes the text to lower cases/
- if I type in "-lower -upper" then it only changes the text to upper cases/

the snippet of my program is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  int ch;
  int arg;
  char buf[100];
  int upper = 0;
  int lower = 0;

  for( arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++ )
  {
      if( strcmp( argv[arg] , "-upper") == 0 )
      {
        upper = 1;
      }
      if( strcmp( argv[arg] , "-lower") == 0)
      {
        lower = 1;
      }
       if( strcmp( argv[arg] , "-lower -upper") == 0 )
      {
        upper = 1;
      }
      else if( strcmp( argv[arg] , "-upper -lower") == 0)     
      {
        lower = 1;
      }

      else
      {
        fprintf(stderr,"Invalid command line option\n" );
    return 0;
      }
  }

  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) //deal with cmd args
```

However, `strcmp` doesn't handle the whitespaces. So the issue arised is that C program will not treat "-lower -upper" as "to uppercase". How can I compare the cmd args including the whitespaces so that it will handle "-lower -upper" the same as "-upper"?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Why not process `"-upper -lower"` as two *separate* arguments? You may also find this helpful [**Convert the input from C program using command line**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38298911/convert-the-input-from-c-program-using-command-line/38299396#38299396)

Comment: For that to work you could pass `"-lower -upper"` (quoted) or escape the space with `\\`. Your shell splits the arguments on whitespace before passing them as arguments to your program. (at least on un*x).

Comment: Did you type in `./nameofprogram -lower -upper` or `./nameofprogram "-lower -upper"`? The former is two separate arguments, *not* one argument with whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply clear lower when upper is set or the opposite, *ie.* the last argument clears the old ones:

```
int upper = 0;
int lower = 0;

for( arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++ )
{
    printf("parsing %s\n", argv[arg]);
    if( strcmp( argv[arg] , "-upper") == 0 )
    {
        printf("Now in upper mode\n");
        lower = 0;
        upper = 1;
        continue;
    }
    if( strcmp( argv[arg] , "-lower") == 0)
    {
        printf("Now in lower mode\n");
        upper = 0;
        lower = 1;
        continue;
    }

    fprintf(stderr,"Invalid command line option\n" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But what should I do when the cmd line args is "-lower -upper"?

Comment: I need  "-lower -upper" to be equivalent to be "-upper" but since the cmd line args will go thru that "-lower" part, it will parses all the read chars to lowercase and that's the major issue I have encountered. I simply can't have "-lower -upper" to be all upper cases

Comment: @TommyTang I just noticed a problem in `if/else` condition, I updated my code.

Comment: @TommyTang The idea of my code is to **take in account only the last argument**, you could have `./program -upper -upper -upper -upper -lower`, it would be equivalent  `./program -lower`

Comment: thank you !!
Do you have any idea how to fix the issue I had btw? I tried offseting the lower or upper but it doesn't really work because when I have two cmd args together, say, "-upper -lower" the program will go thru the "-upper" part first and then every letter will be casted to uppercases which is not the result I want.

Comment: @TommyTang try with some debugging traces (I updated my code)

Answer (score 0):

For command line utilities on Unix, it's generally the last flag on the command line that take precedence over the previous flags. Thus, `ls -C -1` will list the files in the current directory in a single column, not in multiple columns, while `ls -1 -C` has the opposite effect.

You should not need to compare pairs or other combinations of command line flags.

If flag `-upper` is present, set a variable `do_upper=1`. If next you find `-lower` set `do_upper=0`.

Since `-upper` and `-lower` are mutually exclusive, it doesn't make sense to keep track of to variables in your code. If you do, you end up with silly things like

```
if (do_upper && !do_lower) { ... }
```

In fact, you could have your code default to one of these things, `-lower` for example, and only have a single flag, `-upper`, that changes the default behaviour.  I don't know if that makes sense in your particular application though.

Personally, on Unix, I would stick with single-letter flags and use `getopt()` for command line parsing. It makes my life so much easier than trying to do string manipulation of user-provided data.